# Circular Dependency on OOP

Tags: java, c#, oop, uml

I want to define a base class that represents an item.  Each item has an effect that can be activated. The effect is an interface `IEffect` with an `Active` method, and the `Item` class has an `IEffect` property.

Example:

```
public interface IEffect
{
    void Activate();
}

public class Item
{
    private IEffect mEffect;
}
```

Now I define a class called `ItemList`, that contains a list of item and the current position of selected Item, and another method for manipulating the list.

```
public class ItemList
{
    private int mCurrentPos;
    private List<Item> ...
    ... some methods ...
}
```

This class is used from another class (for example class A), that updates the position and manipulates the list. I want to create an `Effect` class, for example `Effect1` that implements `IEffect`, and the method `Activate` use some methods of class `A`. To do this, the constructor method of `Effect1` accepts an instance of the class `A`.

When I create `ItemList`, that contains some `Item` that use `Effect1` or `Effect2`, `EffectN`. But the class `A` needs of `ItemList` and `Effect1` need of `A`, but I can't create the `ItemList` without `Effect1`, etc...

Comment: it looks like `A` is god object - split it into multiple classes

Comment: Can you show a more complete code sample?  I'm not sure if there's a better way to design what you're doing, because the overall intent of the system seems a little vague as a contrived example.  But perhaps a more complete code sample can demonstrate the issue.  Specifically, this statement sounds suspect: `"the method Activate use some methods of class A"`  Why does it need methods that are on `A`?  How are those responsibilities related?  And if they *are* related and the structure is legitimate, why can't classes pass references to themselves when creating other class objects as needed?

Comment: I want to create a simple game, the class A receive the events fired from ItemList, and the method Activate modify in the class A some Item of ItemList, alternatively, the Activate method can directly modify ItemList, but the problem of circular dependency persist.

Comment: Can you please provide your UML model since you tagged your question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Based on your comments it looks like you have a coupling issue in your code. Take a look at this website [Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html) to learn how to properly pattern your game so you do not end up in this type of situation.

*Edit*: Adding additional [Design Patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns), [Wikipedia Link to Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) which may help in situations like these.

Sometimes when creating a complex system such as game system interactions it requires you to rethink about how you initially created the system, it may also require a complete rewrite of the entire system from scratch. Learning the design patterns professional game developers use (first link) and learning about design patterns that are applicable to all OOP programming languages (second link) will ensure that you create a design which prevents you from entering into a situation in the question.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Instead of using the constructor to keep track of `class A` modify your methods to accept `class A` as a parameter/argument in your `IEffect` interface.

```
public interface IEffect
{
    void Activate(A instance);
}
```

When you're iterating over the `ItemList` inside your `Class A` pass `this` or the instance of `Class A` into the methods of the `IEffect` interface. This will allow you to call the methods from `Class A` inside your `Class Effect`, `Class Effect1`, `Class Effect2`, etc. without having a circular dependency.

Do not store `Class A` inside your `Class Effect`'s.

Comment: Yes, but if want define another Effect, for example Effect2 that modify another class I can't reuse the IEffect interface

Comment: If that is the case, it's not a circular dependency issue, it's a coupling issue. Edit: Will be editing the answer in a minute.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I want to create a general IEffect interface. The effect can be applied on the ItemList. I know I'm trying to create a list of items with the effects that modify the same list, I do not know how to fix it

Comment: I've modified the answer to give you a good location to learn a lot about game design patterns. You should find the decoupling chapter to be very helpful.

Comment: I can't find a solution for my problem, with the decoupling models.

Comment: If you weren't able to find the answer in the decoupling section of the link I posted, then you will need to rethink about your design. It's possible that the design itself is flawed.  Here is a link to additional [Design Patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns). If none of these will fit your situation it's definitely a design flaw.